# Restrict access to specific url htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I need to restrict access to this specific domain:

mydomain.com/wp-admin

I tried this code but didn't work

```
RewriteRule ^wp-admin(?!/something\.php/allow/this/uri/?$) - [F,L,NC]
```

How can I do this, please?

Answer (score 2):

**Single IP address access**

To allow access from a single IP address, replace `123\.123\.123\.123` with your own IP address:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

**Multiple IP address access**

> You can [check your IP to get your computer's IP address](http://support.inmotionhosting.com/ipcheck.php).

To allow access from multiple IP addresses, replace `123\.123\.123\.xxx` with your own IP addresses:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.121$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.122$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

**Dynamic IP address access, limit by referer**

If your IP address changes, you can protect your WordPress site by only allowing login requests coming directly from your domain name. Simply replace `example\.com` with your own domain name

Most brute force attacks rely on sending direct `POST` requests right to your `wp-login.php` script. So requiring a `POST` request to have your domain as the referrer can help weed out bots.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.*)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

Wait at least *15-20 minutes*, and try to login to your WordPress site again. If you try to access the WordPress dashboard within the *15 minute* window of a block, this could extend the block longer.
It's important to wait for the previous block to expire and be patient before attempting to access your WordPress site again.

[source](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/lock-down-wordpress-admin-login-with-htaccess)

For you case if you want to restrict that `url yourdomainname.com/wp-admin`, use this :

```
<files wp-login.php>
# set up rule order
order deny,allow
# default deny
deny from all
allow from x.x.x.x
allow from y.y.y.y
allow from z.z.z.z
</files>

 ErrorDocument 401 default
 ErrorDocument 403 default
 ErrorDocument 404 default
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort but actually I don't want to restrict the ip,
I only want to restrict that url
mydomainname.com/wp-admin

Comment: Ok i've added what you need in the last part of the answer @Marwa

Comment: I think this method would restrict access to certain ips .. Isn't there a method other than restricting by ip? I need to restrict the url itself as it is

Comment: @Marwa yep look at the last part of the answer it block all access but the the ips that you add

Comment: I need a method without using ips, a method that restricting a url without using ips, isn't there a method to achieve this ??

Comment: You wan't to block any access to admin url !? @Marwa

Comment: yes, please .. I want to block any access to admin url